# Wagtail 1.0: RoutablePageMixin throws TypeError: serve() takes exactly 5 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

After implementing a RoutablePage as documented, I created a page and then tried to render it. That's when I get the error. After some digging, it looks like it starts at the wagtailcore/urls.py and the problem is the call to serve() is located in the wagtailcore/views.py that doesn't match the RoutablePage serve function defined here. This is my code:

```
class OfficeRoutes(RoutablePageMixin):

    @route(r'^offices/(?P<office_id>[\w-]+)/$', name="offices")
    def office_landing_view(self, request, office_id, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("this isn't working")


class OfficePage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full")
    ]
```

What could be the issue? I have a strong feeling that I'm missing some concept about how RoutablePages are used. The return from the @route function was mostly a guess.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!